How do I find the stud?
I am trying to mount my TV above my fireplace. I detected a vertical line of drywall screws but when I drilled between them I found no wood. Any idea what is going on?



"Found no wood" - that can mean "empty space" or it can mean "blocked by something, but not wood". Some buildings (especially but not exclusively apartment buildings) have metal studs instead of wood studs. They will feel like "nail plates" to a typical drill with a bit designed for wood but they are actually designed to be drilled through,. But the mounting hardware is different than for wood studs.

I found only drywall and insulation

you did not find the drywall screws, use a magnet to find them

@Traveler Is that not "The StudBuddy's" job?

@gnicko StudBuddy® Magnetic Stud Finder is a magnet
`

You should search this site regarding trying to install TVs over a fire place. You will find plenty of very good reasons why this is a bad idea.

What was mounted there across the three holes?

@Huesmann I tried to mount the the TV because I didn’t realize I hadn’t hit the stud but it was not solid.

Get a coat hanger. Straighten it. Bend it 90-deg at 9". Insert the 9" part into the hole you made. Turn it until you hit a stud.

Useful trick. You probably didn't miss by much. Remember that screws are not always well centered on the stud, especially where two pieces of wallboard meet
